# Spring security based SSO for multiple web applications

Tags: single-sign-on

I have multiple web based applications which are communicating with each other using Restful web services. Communication among applications is not secure (No Authentication/Authorization implemented).

I want to create a new application which will act as a Authentication server for all other applications, which means any request coming to any application will be authenticated by the Authentication server first and after successful authentication, server will return a token or attach a cookie to request for further communication.

I am considering to use Spring security to implement Authentication server.

Also, I want to create a client using spring security which will be integrated with other application to interact with Authentication server.

How to achieve this?

Below is the diagrammatic representation of the problem statement
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to note is that authentication and session management are different questions, and you'll want to take that into account while designing the system.

Authentication consists of answering the question "Who are you? Are you really who you claim to be?". This is usually done by either something the user has (like a private key), something the user knows (like a password), or something the user is (like a fingerprint).

Session management is a different question. Once you authenticate a user, you need to bind that authenticated identity to multiple calls over time. For something like SSH, this is built into the protocol. However, HTTP is stateless, so you need to create some sort of passed around state (like cookies) that tracks this identity over time.

For a raw authentication server, you might want to look into the [OpenId Connect Protocol](http://openid.net/connect/). It's essentially an extension on OAuth intended for dealing with identity. Also, make sure to read the [OWASP Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet).

For session management, the [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) is a useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

SSO can be handled by several protocols: CAS, SAML, OpenID Connect and even OAuth.

I would not create a new application to do that, but choose an existing implementation and properly configure it (Examples: https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas, https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server...)

Considering you have UI interactions and application to application interactions, OpenID Connect is a good choice, see this excellent presentation: https://vimeo.com/113604459

And [`spring-security-pac4j`](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) can work with all these protocols.